# Shunting Yard Algorithm extension and implementation issues

Tags: algorithm, go, compiler-construction, implementation, abstract-syntax-tree

Let me introduce you to my current project (that obviously yields the problem I face  hence I post here).  I am writing a  so-called  "compiler" for  a simplistic language.  I have already built a VM to run  the produced bytecode, the associated Lexer   (all this project  is  an optional  assignment).  My  problem lies  in the Expression parsing bit.  I use the Shunting Yard Algorithm by  Dijkstra to convert my postfix expressions into the corresponding AST structure, and I am incapable of adjusting the algorithm correctly to generate the correct AST if -and only if- I try to implement function calls and array subscript.

Here a sample of the algorithm implementation (everything is pretty self-explanatory I believe)

```golang
func (p *parser) shuntingyard(input token.TQueue) *ast.Node {
    var operands ast.NStack
    var operators *token.TStack

    operands = make(ast.NStack, 0)
    operators = token.TokenStack()

    for tok := input.Dequeue(); tok.Sym != "EOF"; tok = input.Dequeue() {
        switch tok.Kind {
        case "LParen":
            operators.Push(tok)
        case "RParen":
            for {
                // pop item ("(" or operator) from stack
                if operators.Empty() {
                    p.errorf("Unmatched parenthesis on line %d, expected '(' to match closing parenthesis in expression", p.lno)
                }

                op := operators.Pop()
                if op.Sym == "(" {
                    break // discard "("
                }

                if isUnary(op.Sym) {
                    node := ast.MakeNode(*op)
                    node.AddChild(operands.Pop())
                    operands.Push(node)
                    break
                }

                RHS := operands.Pop()
                LHS := operands.Pop()
                operands.Push(ast.MakeParentNode(*op, RHS, LHS))
            }
        default:
            if o1, isOp := prOps[tok.Sym]; isOp {
                // token is an operator
                for !operators.Empty() {
                    // consider top item on stack
                    op := operators.PeekTop()
                    if o2, isOp := prOps[op.Sym]; !isOp || o1.prec > o2.prec || o1.prec == o2.prec && o1.rAssoc {
                        break
                    }

                    // top item is an operator that needs to come off
                    op = operators.Pop()
                    if isUnary(op.Sym) {
                        node := ast.MakeNode(*op)
                        node.AddChild(operands.Pop())
                        operands.Push(node)
                        break
                    }
                    RHS := operands.Pop()
                    LHS := operands.Pop()
                    operands.Push(ast.MakeParentNode(*op, RHS, LHS))
                }
                // push operator (the new one) to stack
                operators.Push(tok)
            } else {
                operands.Push(ast.MakeNode(*tok))
            }
        }
    }

    // drain stack to result
    for !operators.Empty() {
        if operators.PeekTop().Sym == "(" {
            p.errorf("Unmatched parenthesis on line %d, expected ')' to match previous parenthesis in expression", p.lno)
        }

        RHS := operands.Pop()
        LHS := operands.Pop()
        operands.Push(ast.MakeParentNode(*operators.Pop(), RHS, LHS))
    }

    result := operands.Pop()
    for !operands.Empty() {
        result.AddSibling(operands.Pop())
    }

    return result
}
```

The idea is pretty straightforward when you encounter a binary operator from the operator stack, you pop off of the operand stack two nodes that you set as children of the operator encountered (or one if the operator is unary). And you push the resulting node on the operands stack.

For instance, this input:

```
c = 0;
a = 1 << 3 + 2;
```

results in the (valid) AST:

```
┣━ Assign           =
┃   ┣━ Identifier       'a'
┃   ┗━ Lshift           <<
┃       ┣━ Number           1
┃       ┗━ Plus             +
┃           ┣━ Number           3
┃           ┗━ Number           2
┗━ Assign           =
    ┣━ Identifier       'c'
    ┗━ Number           0
```

However, the output is being wrong whenever I try to nest function calls:

```
 foo(bar(0))
```

the result is (obviously) not correct:

```
┣━ Number           0
┣━ Function         bar
┗━ Function         foo
```

when I should have had:

```
┗━ Function         foo
    ┗━ Function         bar
        ┗━ Number        0
```

My first question is: **What modification do I have to bring to my implementation to support AST generation for function calls ?** Since all I have found on the Internet regarding the SY Algorithm is always generating an RPN string ...

Another thing is that an input such as:

```
-i++;
```

generates the valid output:

```
┗━ UnaryMinus       -u
    ┗━ PlusPlus         ++
        ┗━ Identifier       'i'
```

but `(-i++);` reports and unbalanced parenthesised expression ?

The `map` used to work with operators is:

```golang
var prOps = map[string]struct {
    prec   int
    rAssoc bool
}{
    "++" : {50, false}, "--" : {50, false},

    "."  : {40, false}, "["  : {40, false},

    "!"  : {30, true}, "~"   : {30, true},
    "-u" : {29, true}, "--u" : {29, true}, "++u": {29, true},
    "**" : {28, true},

    "*"  : {27, false}, "/"  : {27, false}, "%" : {27, false},
    "+"  : {26, false}, "-"  : {26, false},
    ">>" : {25, false}, "<<" : {25, false},
    ">"  : {24, false}, ">=" : {24, false}, "<" : {24, false}, "<=" : {24, false},
    "==" : {23, false}, "!=" : {23, false},
    "&"  : {22, false},
    "^"  : {21, false},
    "|"  : {20, false},
    "&&" : {19, false},
    "||" : {18, false},

    "="  : {10, true}, "+="  : {10, true}, "-=" : {10, true}, "*="  : {10, true},
    "/=" : {10, true}, "**=" : {10, true}, "^=" : {10, true}, "~="  : {10, true},
    "|=" : {10, true}, "&="  : {10, true}, "%=" : {10, true}, "<<=" : {10, true},
    ">>=": {10, true},
    ","  : {9, false},
}
```

Where `-u`, `++u`, `--u` are the instances of the meant operator, but unarily.

On the other note, is the Shunting Yard Algorithm what I **truly** need ? I mean, if parsing an object-oriented expression with this algorithm [is feasable](https://github.com/eriksank/dijkstra-shunting-yard), is that my best choice ?

I also read (a lot) on parsers in a larger sense. I believe, from what I read, that writing a Recursive Descent parser is my best chance to achieve my goal within reasonable amount of time. I read some source codes, but parsers tend not to be reader-friendly. **What is a guideline I should keep for this project regarding the parser and AST generation ?**

Please tell me if I did anything wrong with this thread :) And do ask if I missed to link/give any ressources needed !

In the hope of having some helpful answers.

Comment: Your project looks pretty interesting, around six months I did a little parser for Boolean expressions and the source code of Go helped me a lot with the parser and [lexer](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/go/scanner) refreshing my knowledge about languages theory. I recommend you take a look to the [go](https://golang.org/pkg/go/) package of Go :) Btw, I'm a big fan of Dijkstra

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on a better suited Stack Exchange site. In future, please only post your question on a single Stack Exchange site. For more information, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64939/shunting-yard-algorithm-extension-and-ast-generation